# What projection should I use in D3 to plot my longitude/latitude coordinates on an OpenStreetMap SVG image?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, openstreetmap, projection

I'm trying to automatically grab a slice of map from openstreetmap, and then plot some points (in [longitude,latitude]) on to the svg image I have from openstreetmap. I have the long/lat bounds of the openstreetmap svg image, its width/height, and the openstreetmap "scale" number (although now I realize it might not mean the same as the scale in d3).

What projection would I use to convert the long/lat I have into coordinates of the openstreetmap image? I've read through a ton of stackoverflow posts on d3 and projections, and tried every single one of them but the points I plot are still way off. Here's one of the projections I tried:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale(360*width/(longleft - longright)))
.center([center long/lat from openstreetmap])
.translate([width/2, height/2]);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5616813 might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that applies to my question. I want to compute the projection, rather than use a pre-specified one.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but the linked one with zooming and panning might help too - bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150

Comment: The one in the example uses

.scale((1 << 21) / 2 / Math.PI)

but need to compute the scale parameter because I have an openstreetmap svg that was already scaled when I download it. If I just use an arbitrary scale, then when I plot my long/lat points, they will be in the wrong place...